# What is LOBYTE in C++

Tags: c++, byte

I recently started learning C++ and assembly. I came across `LOBYTE` when I disassembled something in IDA and viewed the function in pseudo code.

After reading the [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/windows/desktop/legacy/ms632658(v=vs.85)?redirectedfrom=MSDN) at MSDN, I still don't understand.

What is a low order byte? Can someone tell me more on what it's used for and an example of its usage in C++?

Comment: I think may be related to [Endianess](http://teaching.idallen.com/cst8281/10w/notes/110_byte_order_endian.html). However I'm not sure. I mean, why wouldn't Microsoft just use the right word?

Answer (score 20):

`LOBYTE` and `HIBYTE` along with `HIWORD` and `LOWORD`, are macros used to extract a word or a byte from a larger set of bytes/words.

As an example, say you have the two bytes `24 FF`, which make a word. You have this value stored in a `unsigned short ushortvar` in your program. Now you can extract either of the two bytes by using `HIBYTE(ushortvar)` or `LOBYTE(ushortvar)`. The first will be equal to `0x24`, and the latter will be equal to `0xff`. You can do the same with a `unsigned int` to extract a one of the words by using `LOWORD` respectively `HIWORD`.