# The meaning of LOBYTE(some_var) = 0; in IDA HexRays?

Tags: reverse-engineering, ida

I read some info about LOBYTE being a macros to extract low byte, but what I see there is something totally weird. It looks for me like setting value to a function -_- I am not pro reverse engeneer and doing it, because I don't have other options left.

So some algorithm read file byte-by-byte. Somewhere it do

```
fread(&third_block_first_zero_byte, 1u, 1u, hd6_file_ptr);
```

then later it do

```
LOBYTE(third_block_first_zero_byte) = 0;
```

So... what the hell it do? Extracting low byte from a single byte variable... ouch... that hurts my brain.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two lines of code are unrelated.

```
fread(&third_block_first_zero_byte, 1u, 1u, hd6_file_ptr);
```

The fread function in this case returns a single element from a file object stream located in memory ('hd6_file_ptr' is a pointer to the stream).

```
LOBYTE(third_block_first_zero_byte) = 0;
```

Above line just retrieves low-order Byte from value currently stored within 'third_block_first_zero_byte' variable & reassigns it value zero.

Similar query [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18033192/c-lobyte-please-explain-more)

Reference:
http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdio/fread/